Incorrect Mesh Depth When Exporting (as GLTF)
I modeled a grass field with geometry nodes. 1 big plane serving as ground, 1 grass plane-mesh instanced and scattered on the main plane. Everything looks fine in Blender when I apply the modifier. When I export this scene as GLTF (and view it in any GLTF viewer), farthest mesh gets rendered in front of the nearest mesh to the camera. This looks totally different than before exporting. How can I solve this?
Edit: In Blender 4.3, grass material has Settings -> Surface -> Render Method is Dithered. However, Blender 4.3 completely ignores this setting when exporting to GLTF. When I open the .glb file, the Render Method: Blended is selected.
TL;DR: This is not the case in Blender 4.0. Also, 4.0 has "Blend Mode" instead of "Render Method". "Blend Mode: Alpha Clip" is exported as "Blend Mode: Alpha Clip". So, my guess is, a bug is preventing 4.3 to export "Render Method" option.


